# Last Index of (+,-,*,/) from a certain index

Tags: java, string

I am currently making a calculator that would separate the user input into terms based on (+,-,*,/), I cannot figure out how to make the last index of (+,-,*,/) before a certain index.
This is my code:

```
private static int findlastSymbol(int endingIndex) {
        if (endingIndex == -1) {
            int lastArg = 32768;
            int smallestValue = 0;
            if (in.lastIndexOf('+')>smallestValue) {
                lastArg = in.lastIndexOf("+");

            }
            else if (in.lastIndexOf('-')>smallestValue) {
                lastArg = in.lastIndexOf("-");
            }
            else if (in.lastIndexOf('*')>smallestValue) {
                lastArg = in.lastIndexOf("*");
            }
            else if (in.lastIndexOf('-')>smallestValue) {
                lastArg = in.lastIndexOf("*");
            }
            return lastArg;
        }
        int lastArg = endingIndex;

        if (in.lastIndexOf("+",endingIndex)>lastArg) {
            lastArg = in.lastIndexOf("+",endingIndex);
            System.out.println(lastArg);
        }
        else if (in.lastIndexOf("-",endingIndex)>lastArg) {
            lastArg = in.lastIndexOf("-",endingIndex);
            System.out.println(lastArg);
        }
        else if (in.lastIndexOf("*",endingIndex)>lastArg) {
            lastArg = in.lastIndexOf("*",endingIndex);
            System.out.println(lastArg);
        }
        else if (in.lastIndexOf("*",endingIndex)>lastArg) {
            lastArg = in.lastIndexOf("*",endingIndex);
            System.out.println(lastArg);
        }
        return lastArg;
    }
```

The output only gives the input value when the input is not -1
This is the rest of my program:

```
private static string in = "1+2+3+4+5";
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println(findlastSymbol(4));
}
```

And this is my output:

```
4
```

*Should be 3*

And this is my output when i do

```
System.out.println(findlastSymbol(-1));
```

```
5
```

*Which is correct.*

Can someone help me find the issue in my code

Comment: Your current approach seems to be on the wrong track, and you should be looking into writing rudimentary _parser_ which can handle basic arithmetic expressions.

Comment: turns out im just dumb and all i had to do was to change the `int lastArg = endingIndex;` to `int lastArg = 0`

Comment: Please check your code neatly ... since i am seeing some duplicates in 1st if 4th ```else if``` block ... it sould be ```'/'``` and on the last ```else if``` block where it should be ```'/'```

or it that what it is supposed to be